# How to start electron desktop application as Administrator

Tags: node.js, electron, desktop-application, electron-packager

I have create an Electron desktop Application. I have used `electron-packager` to create packaging of electron. Using that package I have created windows setup through `electron-winstaller`. My application requires some admin privileges so I want my application to run as Administrator every time. I have used `sudo-prompt` to prompt user for UAC. But it prompts each time when I use `sudo.exec()` function.